# facebook automatic likes with qr codes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, qr-code

Hello friends i was wondering is there any way through which if someone scan my qr code it should automatically like my Facebook page..]
I have tried developers pages code for like button but it shows up big like button instead getting automatic like

Comment: You may find a temporary solution by exploring the way Facebook works, but it will whange in the future. Facebook does not want this to be possible, they want people to use their App and everything that goes around: there is no real solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible via the Graph API, and Facebook also does this on purpose. Likes should be based on real user interactions.